# Moving questions from one account to other

Tags: discussion

I need to move some of the questions I asked on Stack Overflow from my personal account to other account (which will be work related). Is there a way to do that on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Why do the question need to be moved? And why do you need to maintain two separate accounts for home and work?

Comment: sorry for replying late. The answer for both questions is I don't want to mix work + non-work questions if I give reference to one of the questions I asked to someone at work and vice versa.